# Webmethod with EnableSession=true attribute

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asmx, pagemethods

I have a ASP.NET 3.5 web application in which I have used many PageMethods.
WebMethod(EnableSession = true), does this attribute hamper the performance of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Probably no. The performance overhead isn't noticeable at all until complex datatypes like DataSet's are stored in the session.